# "ReferenceError: monaco is not defined" when trying to set up a BlazorMonaco editor

Tags: c#, blazor, monaco-editor, referenceerror

I am trying to setup a BlazorMonaco editor, but I keep on getting the error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'u1AmXKcme53TZumhysV_MenrWwA9xjflVubUoLRRQzk'.
      Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: monaco is not defined
ReferenceError: monaco is not defined
```

Inspecting the compiled JavaScript, it seems that the issue is in the `_content/BlazorMonaco/lib/monaco-editor/min-maps/vs/out-editor/vs/loader.js` file. The error displayed in the console is:

```
properties of undefined (reading 'define')
    at loader.js:1961:33
    at loader.js:1973:13
```

which points to this line in loader.js:

```
if (typeof AMDLoader.global.define !== 'function' || !AMDLoader.global.define.amd) {
```

**Code:**

I followed the steps explained on the [BlazorMonaco](https://github.com/serdarciplak/BlazorMonaco) GitHub repository. A summary of the steps I implemented:

1. Installed the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorMonaco/) package to the project.
2. Add the script tags in our HTML `<head>`:

```
<script src="_content/BlazorMonaco/jsInterop.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorMonaco/lib/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorMonaco/lib/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
```

3. Create the following `.razor` component:

```
@using BlazorMonaco
@using BlazorMonaco.Editor

<h3>Code Editor</h3>

<StandaloneCodeEditor @ref="_editor" Id="sample-code-editor-123" ConstructionOptions="EditorConstructionOptions" />

@code {
    private StandaloneCodeEditor _editor = null!;
    private string _valueToSet = "";

    private StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions EditorConstructionOptions(StandaloneCodeEditor editor)
    {
        return new StandaloneEditorConstructionOptions
        {
            Language = "javascript",
            GlyphMargin = true,
            Value = "\"use strict\";\n" +
                    "function Person(age) {\n" +
                    "   if (age) {\n" +
                    "       this.age = age;\n" +
                    "   }\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "Person.prototype.getAge = function () {\n" +
                    "   return this.age;\n" +
                    "};\n"
        };
    }
}
```

I cannot find any information as to why this error occurs. It seems like we need a `Monaco` package of some sorts?

Comment: Do you see any additional error / warning or info besides the given one in the browser console? The error indicates that something in the JavaScript part breaks so we need additional clue here. You could also set a JavaScript breakpoint in the shown `.js` files to identify the actual line that causes the error.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I improved the error description to include the point where it breaks in the JavaScript.

Comment: I think you are facing some sort of side effect here as your example works on my side with VS 2022 17.6.0 Preview 2.0. Last resort: remove everything from the project step by step until you don't get the said error anymore or start with a new project.

Answer (score 1):

We managed to solve the error. One of the problems occurred in step 2, and the corrected method is to add the script tags (see step 2) to your HTML **`<body>`** tag, and not the `<head>` tag as mentioned in the question. Note that these script tags must be placed after the script tag for the `blazor.webassembly.js` file.

In other words, the `<body>` tag in your `wwwroot/index.html` file should look something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <svg class="loading-progress">
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
            <circle r="40%" cx="50%" cy="50%" />
        </svg>
        <div class="loading-progress-text"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Loading modules for BLAZOR MONACO -->
    <script src="_content/BlazorMonaco/jsInterop.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/BlazorMonaco/lib/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/BlazorMonaco/lib/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

---

As @ViRuSTriNiTy mentioned, though, the error was because of a side-effect that occurred when implementing the Monaco editor in our existing project. We also have ag-grid in our project, and initially used a cdn link to import ag-grid into a JavaScript file.

```
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.js";
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js";
```

Having both ag-grid and BlazorMonaco as part of our project, gave the error:

```
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Can only have one anonymous define call per script file
```

Replacing the cdn links with a `<script>` tag in the HTML `<head>` in `wwwroot/index.html`, solved this issue.

```
<!-- Loading modules for AG GRID  -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-enterprise@29.3.2/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css"/>
```